# Getting Return Value from AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP script that checks an email address to determine if it is valid or not. The function simply returns `true` or `false`. I am trying to implement an ajax call to the php file and return the `true` or `false` back to the javascript function. Currently I am getting nothing.

```
function validateForm() {
    var email = document.forms["contact"]["email"].value;
    var validEmail;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "validateEmail.php",
        data: "email=" + email,
        success: function(result) {
            validEmail = result;
            console.log('result: ' + validEmail);
        }
    });
}
```

If I can retrieve the `true` or `false` I will then do some boolean checking to determine how to proceed. The function `validateForm()` is being called when the user clicks a form Submit button.

```
<form name="contact" action="submitOrder.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
```

I'd like the `validateForm()` function to return false if the email address is not valid so that submitOrder.php is never called but due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX, I am not sure how to do this.

**UPDATE**

The request is working correctly (I'm pretty sure). This is what I am seeing in Firebug.
[image]
I'm still not seeing anything returned. The console prints "result: ". I also changed validateEmail.php to return the number 17 and I still get nothing returned.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: check your console and network traffic to see if the request is being sent

Comment: how do you check if the email address is valid?

Comment: It appears to be posting properly. See screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation&ei=7P_HT-yeD6qi2QWs4qjjDQ&usg=AFQjCNGchUA4S60RlCTK8C6oY3QtcpBvfA&cad=rja) plugin.  Would be a lot simpler then hashing this out from scratch.

Comment: I added that and I like it alot. Thanks. I don't think it has a check for telephone number. Is this something I could add?

Comment: Yes. You can add it like this: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/phoneUS

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's ajax function is by default asynchronous. Meaning it makes the ajax request and then returns. You probably need to set the `async` parameter to false and then set `validEmail` in your success function like you are doing. Then you can safely return validEmail after the ajax call.

```
function validateForm() {
  var email = document.forms["contact"]["email"].value;
  var validEmail = false;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "validateEmail.php",
    async: false,
    data: "email=" + email,
    success: function(result) {
        validEmail = result;
        console.log('result: ' + validEmail);
    }
  });

  return validEmail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a missing ; at the end of your jquery call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "validateEmail.php",
    data: "email=" + email,
    success: function(result) {
        validEmail = result;
        console.log('result: ' + validEmail);
    }
});
```

I'd recommend installing firebug so you can see what's going on with the ajax calls & responses - you should be able to debug it a lot easier then.

Comment: I've got Firebug (see screenshot) and I think it's posting, but I'm just not getting a response.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the Ajax call submit if the result is valid if you don't want to make the AJAX call synchronous. Call your validateForm and return false to the onsubmit. (I wouldn't make validateForm itself return false as that would not be orthogonal).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need an event.preventDefault(); to get the async call to work correctly

$('#submit-button-id').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});

This should stop the browser from submitting the form before any sort of validation is done. (Note, you'll want to give your submit button a class or ID that you can reference in order for this to fire).

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use the synchronous option for ajax calls because it can temporarily lock the browser. Notice the following quote from [jquery's ajax() page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

> Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active.

Instead you can have the button that submits the form call the validateForm function and when the ajax success is called it can submit the form.

```
function validateForm() {
    var email = document.forms["contact"]["email"].value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "validateEmail.php",
        data: "email=" + email,
        success: function(result) {
            if (result == true)
                document.forms["contact"].submit();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `async: false` is a poor way to use AJAX as you block up your javascript unnecessarily.  Using a client side validator such as jQuery Validate is dangerous, as an attacker can disable javascript and submit an invalid form.  Server side validation is a must and it can be done with good old AJAX!

The key is a callback.  Anything you try to return from `validateForm` will be returned before your AJAX call returns because AJAX is asynchronous (non-blocking).  This means you can't return the value from your AJAX success function without pausing all javascript execution.  Instead, you pass in a callback function as a parameter that your AJAX success function can call.  Inside that callback, you can do your boolean checking to figure out how to proceed.  You can also do this directly inside the success function (which is actually a callback!) but the callback parameter and other function decouples the code a little bit, which is good practice.  I modified your code to give you an example of what I mean.

```
function validateForm(callback) {
    var email = document.forms["contact"]["email"].value;
    var validEmail;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "validateEmail.php",
        data: "email=" + email,
        success: function(result) {
            validEmail = result;
            console.log('result: ' + validEmail);
            callback(result);
        }
    });
}

function doSomethingWithResult(result) {
    if (result === True) {
        // Do true stuff
    } else {
        // Do false stuff
    }
}

validateForm(doSomethingWithResult);
```